# No reputation change for "Voting corrected"?

Tags: support, voting-correction

I noticed there was a "Voting corrected" event yesterday on my [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14165730/mck?tab=reputation&sort=post), but there was no associated reputation change.

[image]

I wonder what was actually corrected?

Comment: Probably an upvote that didn’t yield +10 rep due to the reputation cap was removed.

Comment: You mistakenly earned nothing, so they took that away from you.... xD

Comment: Fake votes ....

Comment: they simply *corrected* the *voting* system (a kind of maintenance)

Comment: I’ve got this bug too, but I never hit the reputation cap. Very strange.

Comment: ... Hmm I just remembered that there are other vote types. But no one reported serial voting with delete/undelete/close/offensive/spam votes. Who knows?

Comment: Could it have been Tiny-Votes™? Or follows? Meta-votes? Though they shouldn't be attached to the reputation page at all.

Comment: @Scratte Why would tiny votes be reversed? No reputation change :). Same for votes on meta. I don't think there is a system that reverses these votes.

Comment: @10Rep Meta votes actually counts on gaining badges. But the votes themselves cannot be seen, as there is no reputation tab. But when "votes" are reversed on main, if doesn't make sense that there is no change in reputation. This is all a big mystery to me.

Comment: @Scratte hmm, I think the change in reputation from reversing votes is not independent of the rep cap. That would explain why this is happening. Since the upvote originally didn't count (because of the rep cap) the reversed upvote also wouldn't count. So this isn't a bug.

Comment: @10Rep Kindly read the entire comment thread here ;) There's a user that never hit that rep cap that had that same entry on their reputation page.. with no change to reputation.

Comment: @Scratte talking about OP here, but yes, you are correct.

Comment: This does appear a bit strange. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the rep cap, which you did not, in fact, hit yesterday or the day before. In fact, from the available information (all public; i.e. not requiring moderator access), it looks like this entry appearing on your reputation history is a bug, or at least I wasn't aware the system added events to your reputation history for what appears to have happened.

Comment: @Makyen Actually, one reason other than the rep cap for no reputation change being shown, is if the vote reversals were on wiki posts. There's no rep associated with that, so I expect the votes would get reversed, but no reputation change would show up. As it happens, the OP has no wiki posts, so that's not the explanation either in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This "voting corrected"  event:

> ⠀⠀⠀[03:00:41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14165730/mck?tab=reputation&sort=time)⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀reversal⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Voting corrected ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed))

in your reputation history yesterday represents the automatic reversal of serial votes which you placed on another user's posts, not the reversal of serial votes which were placed by others on your questions or answers. The votes of yours which were reversed had no impact on your reputation when you placed them, so there was no impact on your reputation when the votes were reversed.

Comment: Do we want users to be aware that this happens with an entry on their reputation page? I mean isn't it easier to find the tipping point when one is "notified" when it's crossed?

Comment: @Scratte I do have some concerns about it. It seems that it would lead to at least some people choosing to vote again, but attempting to use a pattern of voting which wasn't automatically reversed. Prior to looking at this, I thought an entry was only made in the reputation history of the person who voted when their votes caused a reputation change for themselves (i.e. for downvotes on answers and acceptance of an answer). However, this clearly shows that an entry is made in the voter's reputation history when their votes are reversed, even when that has no impact on their reputation.

Comment: I mean... yea, sure, one could use this to fish out the boundaries that you can avoid... but at the same time, knowing that you've crossed one is a slap on the wrist that can certainly have positive effects, such as the user avoiding serial voting in the future.

Comment: I didn't know that when I serial vote another user I get a notification that my votes have been reversed. I remember serial upvoting a user once and I never got a notification about it in my reputation history.